# How to insert columns of data from Excel into fields of an Access database using vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to write a VBA code in Excel that will insert columns of my Excel sheet into fields of my Access database. I'm trying to insert the columns "NDC11", "ProductNameLong", and "ProductName2" into the fields of my Access database which are named "NDC11", "ProductNameLong", and "ProductName2", respecively. This is the code I have so far.

```
Sub DataPuller()

Dim refresh
Dim year As String
Dim intColIndex As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim strProv As String
Dim strConn As String
Dim Conn As New Connection
Dim rsQry As New Recordset
Dim strQry As String
Dim NDCs As Range
Dim ProductName2s As Range

refresh = MsgBox("Start New Query?", vbYesNo)

If refresh = vbYes Then
    year = Application.InputBox("Which year would you like CMS Utilization Data from:" & vbNewLine & "2019, 2020, 2021, or 2022?", "Input Year")
    If year = "2022" Then
        On Error GoTo Whoa
        strPath = "C:\Users\hgarrison\Documents\PRM DOCS\1Q2022 - 4Q2022 CMS Utilization Database.accdb"
        strProv = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        strConn = "Provider=" & strProv & "Data Source=" & strPath
        Conn.Open strConn
        strQry = "DELETE * from MB_without_financials"
        Conn.Execute strQry
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Data"
        
        xlFilepath = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName
        strQry = "INSERT INTO MB_without_financials(NDC11, ProductNameLong, ProductName2) SELECT NDC11, ProductNameLong, ProductName2 FROM [Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & xlFilepath & "].[Sheet1$]"
        Conn.Execute strQry


LetsContinue:
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       On Error Resume Next
       rs.Close
       Set rs = Nothing
       cn.Close
       Set cn = Nothing
       On Error GoTo 0
       Exit Sub
Whoa:
       MsgBox "Error Description :" & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
             "Error at line     :" & Erl & vbCrLf & _
             "Error Number      :" & Err.Number
       Resume LetsContinue
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

My problem is at the "INSERT" SQL query. I get the error saying "No value given for one or more required parameters". How can I insert these columns from excel into these specific Access fields? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure there are no hidden leading spaces in your column header. Code works for me.

Comment: Have you run Debug/Compile? Should have Option Explicit at top of every code module. VBA Editor options can be set to do this automatically when module created. Manually add to existing.

Comment: The SQL syntax works for me but there are other issues with code. Disable the error handler and step debug.

Comment: I have never seen error handling code inside other code structures. Always at very end of procedure.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your comments. I have triple checked that there are no spaces/spelling errors in my column headers and I've removed the error handling code. Upon debugging, it says that Conn.Execute strQry is where I'm getting the error. I can insert values into my Access database fine (e.g. I can do INSERT INTO (NDC11, ProductNameLong, ProductName2) VALUES (1,2,3) and it works fine) so it seems to be something with selecting my columns from Excel. Can I select by column Letter instead (i.e. use A:A instead of the column name)?

Comment: Does the select only give the same error `strQry = "SELECT NDC11, ProductNameLong, ProductName2 FROM [Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & xlFilepath & "].[Sheet1$]"`

Comment: Yes it does indeed. However, if I add single quotes around the column names (i.e. 'NDC11', 'ProductNameLong', and 'ProductName2') I don't get the error. I tried running the original code with this change and got no errors, however the values did not appear in Access (adding in VALUES(1,2,3) still worked). @CDP1802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem... and it's quite embarrassing but some people may face it in the future. My issue was that I am coding the VBA code in PERSONAL.XLSB and I was calling the following:

```
xlFilePath = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

When instead I should have been using:

```
xlFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

Thank you for all your comments though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this short test program to confirm field names

```vb
Sub mydebug()

    Dim conn As Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String, i As Long, msg As String
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    With conn
    
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=Database2.accdb"
        .Open
        
        sql = "SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[Sheet1$]"
        Debug.Print sql
        
        Set rs = conn.Execute(sql)
        For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
            msg = msg & vbLf & i & "  [" & rs.Fields(i - 1).Name & "]"
        Next
        MsgBox "Field Names" & msg, vbInformation
        
    End With

End Sub
```